# DNS issue mail server

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, spf, ptr-record

I tried to find an answer to this one around with no luck so far. I am not a sysadmin, but I work with mailings and one of our server presents some issues.
I do not have personal access to the server, but I think it is a DNS problem, I have an idea on how to fix this, but I would like some help to see if I see it correctly.
The situation (edited message header included)

More in details, starting from the header:

```
Delivered-To: xxxx@xxxxx.com
Received: by yy.yyy.yy.yyy with SMTP id q20csp144570ldr;
    Mon, 29 Sep 2014 04:43:21 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by yy.yyy.yyy.yyy with SMTP id ct2mr42083465wjc.20.1411991001561;
    Mon, 29 Sep 2014 04:43:21 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <email@mydomain.com>
Received: from mail.anotherdomain.com ([12.345.678.999])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id l9si16306803wjf.107.2014.09.29.04.43.21
    for <axxxx@xxxxx.com>;
    Mon, 29 Sep 2014 04:43:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of email@mydomain.com does not designate 12.345.678.999 as      permitted sender) client-ip=78.129.174.107;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=hardfail (google.com: email@mydomain.com.be does not designate 12.345.678.999 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=email@mydomain.com
Received: from www.mydomain.com (thirdplace.com [77.77.777.777])
by mail.anotherdomain.com (Postfix) with SMTP id C951F37F243
for <xxxx@xxxxx.com>; Mon, 29 Sep 2014 13:32:18 +0100 (BST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: htmlMimeMail5
Subject: xxxxx
From: mydomain Be <email@mydomain.com>
Reply-To: email@mydomain.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="=_b084eb0a20927c13afc1e12b48b3a52c"
Message-ID:
```

The main issue is that the server HELOS with mail.anotherdomain.com and the IP 12.345.678.999 PTR record resolves there, but in mail.anotherdomain.com there is not that IP in the DNS. To sort this, is it enough to add an A record?

Then, there is the SPF hardfail you can see, which is because of the SPF record of mydomain.be

So what I would do is:

- adding the from ip 12.345.678.999 in the SPF record of mydomain.com
- adding an A record in mail.anotherdomain.com for 12.345.678.999

And.. that's it? Or should I add also an A record for 12.345.678.999 in mydomain.com?

Thank you if you could be so kind to help me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, the mailserver mail.example.com with 1.2.3.4 serves for mails example.com. The following should apply:

- server helo is mail.example.com
- 1.2.3.4 PTR gives mail.example.com
- mail.example.com resolves to 1.2.3.4
- example.com MX gives mail.example.com
- example.com SPF allows the MX, mail.example.com or 1.2.3.4 directly.

Comment: We did pretty much this same setup 2 days ago and it worked flawlessly. Thank you!